# How do I modify the value of an element in a list of type class containing a string and an integer?

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm new to programming so this is probably a very elementary question. I created a list of a class which contains an integer and a string and I want to change the integer value of a specific index and/or the string name of a specific index. Here is my code:

```
class Sales
    {
        public Sales(string name, int quantitySold)
        {
            Name = name;
            QuantitySold = quantitySold;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int QuantitySold { get; set; }
    }

 class Restaurant
    {
       private List<Sales> _quantityHistory = new List<Sales>();

       public List<Sales> QuantityHistory
       {
            get { return _quantityHistory; }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you want to do. So you simply want to change the value of an object that you are using in your code?

Comment: You mean like `myRestaurant.QuantityHistory[0].QuantitySold = 42;`? (Assuming that `Restaurant myRestaurant = new Restaurant();` and that you have added at least one item to the `QuantityHistory` list.)

Comment: Yes, nothing fancy i'm just a beginner. Specifically an object in a list of a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the property of an object it is fairly simple, let me walk you through it.

```
Sales mySale = new Sales()
```

This is going to be our object, at the moment it is empty as we have just initialized an empty variable, but what if we want to initialize it with a value? Well we can do this:

```
Sales mySale = new Sales()
{
  Name = "SaleName",
  QuantitySold = 5,
};
```

**EDIT** just realised your objects constructor is initializing variables that are passed in as parameters! You don't actually need to have those in the constructor if you have getters and setters and you use the method of creating a variable that I just did above this!

Basically we you first declare the property name that the object holds, followed by the value.

But what if we want to change it somewhere down the track? Well lets pretend that so far in our code we have done exactly like we did above, somewhere down the track somebody makes a purchase so we need to add one more to the QuantitySold of the object, well thats simple just do this:

```
mySale.QuantitySold = mySale.QuantitySold++;
```

Same as the name if we need to change it!

```
mySale.Name = "TheNewSaleName";
```

Basically we just use the variable name of the object we created, followed by a fullstop and the property name and we can change it however we want!

When using a list of objects you can simply search using the index of the list, for instance:

```
_quantityHistory[2].Name = "TheNewNameOfThe3rdObject";
```

Hope this helped buddy.